# mp3 and m4a frequency analysis

Tags: c++, mp3, m4a, frequency-analysis

I'm doing some frequency analysis on mp3 files using FMOD's getSpectrum function and other utilities on windows.  It was working very well but then I tried to load a file from iTunes which is a .m4a and learned that FMOD doesn't support that format on windows (iOS only).

I'm writing pretty much an equalizer that would work with both mp3 and m4a formats that functions on windows and on iOS.  I'm creating this in C++.

Is there an api or middleware I can use to do this with similar functionality to FMOD?  I've been searching but not having much luck.

Thanks

Comment: Why not run an m4a to mp3 converter (or via wav first) and then you can use FMOD on it?

Comment: That might work.  Couple of questions.
1. can it be done real time?
2. is it very cpu intensive - wanted this to run on mobile devices when im finished
3. does it change the actual m4a file? (I'd want it not to)  - Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but - on my computer, wav to mp3 conversion runs much much faster than playing the wav (like 5-10x). Not sure about m4a to wav side or how fast it'd be on a mobile device. I guess you would have to experiment and find out :)

Comment: True true.  I guess it can be done in real time then and wouldn't change the source file?